# Calculate Thevenin voltage in a Common Emitter Circuit

Tags: voltage, circuit-analysis, bjt, thevenin, common-emitter

[image]

I am confused on how to proceed with the above problem. I have solved many problems on thevenin voltage but never faced one involving BJT. Please help me with this problem.

EDIT: I have 2 approaches in my mind.

1st Approach is short ckt a and b and get Isc. Calculate Voc for open circuit case and divide Voc by Isc to get Rth.

[image]

2nd Approach is to calculate re using DC Analysis. Then draw small signal model short circuiting DC and use this circuit to get Rth.

[image]

[image]
Both approaches look perfectly fine. Which one is correct and why?

Comment: It's not entirely fair to throw a non-linear device in a Thevenin equivalent problem, IMO.  However, you can find a Thevenin equivalent by evaluating the open-circuit voltage and the short circuit current.  Can you calculate the current when you short the a-b terminals? And the voltage with a-b open?

Comment: Use Vbe for one part and beta for the other part.

Comment: @JohnD I agree with you. Since the one affects the other this is rather an odd assignment.

Comment: Plz friends take a look at my edited problem.

Comment: I'd say they're both right... and both wrong. Because you are using approximations that make the result with two decimal places wrong, but they are reasonable approximations nonetheless. As a matter of fact, one might just 'look' into the emitter and find the resistance in the base circuit 'amplified' by beta or so (even more crude approximation). - In one case you are approximating Vbe with 0.7V; in the other you are using an approximate formula to compute re...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's been +25 years but I gonna give it a try ...

\$R_{th}=\dfrac{V_{oc}}{I_{sc}}\$

---

**Calculating \$I_{sc}\$** :

\$I_{b}=\dfrac{10.7V - 0.7V}{10k\Omega}=1mA\$

\$I_{c}=I_{b}\cdot\beta =1mA\cdot100=100mA\$

\$I_{sc}=I_{b}+I_{c}=1mA+100mA=101mA\$

---

**Calculating \$V_{oc}\$** :

\$-10.7+10000\cdot I_{b}+0.7+1000\cdot(\beta+1)\cdot I_{b}=0\$

\$10000\cdot I_{b}+1000\cdot101\cdot I_{b}=10\$

\$I_{b}=\dfrac{1}{11100} A\$

\$I_{e}=(\beta+1)\cdot I_{b}=\dfrac{101}{11100}A\$

\$V_{oc}=I_{e}\cdot 1k\Omega=\dfrac{101\cdot1000}{11100}V=\dfrac{1010}{111}V\$

---

\$R_{th}=\dfrac{V_{oc}}{I_{sc}}=\dfrac{\dfrac{1010}{111}V}{101mA}=90.09\Omega\$

---

PS : It's 5:49AM here, time to get some sleep.